# git reset -rf path/to/dir

Tags: git, shell, command-line, terminal

okay. I have a git repo with folders and files / etc.

Everything is tracked.

I need to un-track everything in my a/b/c folder, my c folder contains many folders and files.

this folder has been added to .gitignore, but because the files were already tracked at some point, I cannot seem to find a way to un-track them.

I have tried

```
 git reset a/b/c/*
 git reset -rf a/b/c    ( like rm -rf a/ )
```

and probably 5 other variations of these commands.... and here I am.

any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git rm -r --cached <your directory>
```

Comment: this will remove directory from git tracking but will not remove the directory entirely